# DateTime parses differently when passed via HTTP-POST in body and via HTTP-GET as query params

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, culture

On our MVC 3 Web Application we define the `Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture` with the current user's preferences. However, in one View we submit the data via Ajax always in the format `mm/dd/yyyy` this works fine as long as the user's culture is `en_US`. (obviously)

The surprising thing, it works for all users, when we pass it as HTTP-POST, but stops working when we pass it as HTTP-GET. (In both cases, the exact same value is leaving the browser).

Any ideas why HTTP-POST calls would be handled differently than HTTP-GET?

Also, there are other parameters to that action. In case of an HTTP-POST, they are all set in the body like:

```
{
  "date": "04/15/2016",
  "someText": "Hello World",
  "someNumber": 42
}
```

and for HTTP-GET they are query parameters instead:

```
domain.tld/controller/action?date=04%2F15%2F2016&someText=Hello+World&someNumber=42
```

**Update:**

To avoid confusion, the method is called correctly and returns values in both cases. It's just that the `DateTime` param (which is actually `DateTime?`) isn't being set, just the same as if I'd have set it to some invalid date / string.

Comment: I think your last line of text should read "and for HTTP-GET"

Comment: @SPlatten you're absolutely right, sry for that mistake

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Any ideas why HTTP-POST calls would be handled differently than
>   HTTP-GET?

The default model binder uses the following cultures depending on the HTTPVERB

- InvariantCulture for your HTTPGET
- CurrentCulture for your HTTPPOST requests.

This is because users will share their URLS (HTTPGET) with other users from different cultures.

Imagine we have a user from America who wants to send a URL to their friend in the United Kingdom about an event taking place on 04/15/2016. (15th April 2016). They give their friend the following URL...

```
http://www.myurl.com/tickets/?eventdate=04%2F15%2F2016
```

If we didn't use Invariant Culture then this date would not be valid for our friend in the UK since their culture expects dd/mm/yyyy.

With regards to HTTPPOST, Users will not typically share these types of requests with other users as they are generally generated on a per user basis. Therefore we can explicitly use the CurrentCulture.

You can override this default behaviour by creating your own model binder.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score -1):

Can you please check whether your request handler is `GET or POST`, if it was set to POST then the GET request can't be processed.

**edit**   ** Ignore below one ** : since URL encoding is same in both methods

"The only difference that in `GET` request is all the special characters will be encoded `for. ex / to %2f` where in `POST` it wont happen."